# plot time series and forecast simultaneosusly using autoplot function for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need some help; I have a dataset like that:

```
DATE         COD    QTA
2014-01-02    87      9
2014-01-03    87     23
...           87    ...
Sys.Date()    87     10
2015-03-04    45      5
2015-03-05    45      0
...           45    ...
Sys.Date()    45     11
```

I need to plot, for each value of variable COD, the time series of variable QTA and his forecast simultaneously, showing the date on x-axis.
I need to use Shiny for work but I'm new with that.
So my idea is to create a sidebar panel that let me choose the value of variable COD and then to plot the corresponding time serie with also his forecast.
I know that it's nice to use the autoplot function (or at least the ggplot function).

How can i do this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the latest `ggplot2` and `forecast` packages installed there are two options that should help you here.

1. There is an `autoplot()` method for `forecast` objects.
2. There is also a `geom_forecast()` function the will add a forecast onto your plotted times series.

[This blog post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast7-ggplot2/) from the forecast package creator is better than any example that I could muster.

Comment: Ok but I'd like to see a similar server.R code...